# Do rice noodles have the same bracha as rice?

Tags: blessing

I gather that there was a doubt regarding the beginning bracha of rice whether it should be *Shehakol* or *Mezonot* ( I will try to add in source later.)

Would the same rules apply to rice noodles? Or would it be different because it doesn't look like rice?

Comment: Why would it be any different? I thought it had everything to do with what it's made of, not what it looks like.

Comment: "the beginning bracha of rice" That discussion is already about where it doesn't look like rice. Whole rice kernels are _Adama_ according to everyone, just like whole wheat kernels..

Comment: I’m pretty sure they’re Shehakol; only the five grains retain their Brachos when ground, since that’s how they’re meant to be eaten, as opposed to rice which can be eaten whole. That said, see DoubleAA’s comment.

Answer (score 4):

White rice when cooked is mezonot (not haadama because white rice when crushed and cooked lost the original form already), rice noodles should be no different since rice is the main intention /the majority (normally mezonot would always be the ikkar, but rice is not one of the 5 grains; so we fall back on the intention /proportion). I live in Asia, we eat cooked rice products all the time...

[Hidabroot says](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/200467) that rice noodles (made from rice flour in cooked form) is mezonot, but rice paper is made by steaming rather than cooking so it is shehakol.

[OU also says](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/borei-minei-mezonot/) to bless mezonot over rice cooked and rice pasta
See also [OU's guide](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/) that tomato rice soup can either be mezonot or rice depending on your intention as to which one is the ikkar.

Comment: Not everyone agrees that cooked rice is mezonot.

Comment: Bevadai. ;) Reb Binyomin Forst's Laws of Brachot also holds by mezonot, one of the factors stated was that it is a staple and is satiating. If you think about it it makes sense - many people especially non-Europeans eat rice as a meal.

Comment: The issue though is if rice is Orez, not if Orez gets a Mezonot. Notably, followers of Chabad says Shehakol on rice products since they don't trust the Gra's test to determine if rice is Orez or Dochan. (Of course, to be consistent, everyone who doesn't wear Tekhelet because they 'don't have a Mesorah' should also say Shehakol and not rely on testing, but probably none of them listen to me anyway...)

Comment: the Rosh should be the source for rice being orez, it sustains. where i live, most people eat rice most meals, bread is not a standard thing unless for expats. to call our daily sustenance orez that warrants mezonot followed by borei nefashot just seems very consistent with this food culture.