What to do regarding the Brachah on rice when the only other food you have is Ha'adama?
If one wants to eat cooked rice and a vegetable, should he/can he say Ha'adama on the vegetable first, and have in mind not to cover the rice, so that he can say Shehakol on the rice, according to those who hold that you should say Shehakol on rice, being that there is a question if it is Mezonos or Ha'adama, or is that considered causing oneself to make an unnecessary Brachah?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85252/do-rice-noodles-have-the-same-bracha-as-rice/88675#comment286140_88675
